# Unknown view on top after updating to Xcode 13.3

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, uiview, uinavigationcontroller

After updating to Xcode 13.3 my project compiles normally but on top of my main view controller there is an additional empty navigation view which I have to press the back button to get to the initial view as intended. I haven't change anything in my code other than just updating Xcode. The view hierarchy shows a UIView which but no further info as for the name of that view or any additional info to debug. I can only print:

Printing description of $35:
<UIView: 0x149e702f0; frame = (0 0; 428 926); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x6000012e4b40>>

This happens with the 15.4 simulator.

Any advice is greatly appreciated
[image]

[image]

But when using 15.2 simulator everything works as expected:
[image]

Comment: That view can't come from *nowhere*.  Either your code is presenting it or it is in your storyboard if you are using one.  The fact that you have two UINavigationControllers makes me suspicious that your root UINavigationController has another UINavigationController with a UIViewController

Comment: @Paulw11 Here's the twist. Just downloaded the 15.2 simulator and works as intended. The problem seems to be with 15.4 sim